# Why is my neg_mean_squared_error a positive number for AdaBoostRegressor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

When tuning AdaBoostRegressor using sklearn's `cross_val_score` with `scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'`, it returns a positive number. All of my other algorithms (linear regression, svr, randomforestregressor, etc) return negative numbers. Then I compute the mean of the RMSE scores using `np.mean(np.sqrt(-cross_val_score))`.

Here's the code:

```
# AdaBoost Reg CV
start_time = time.time() # Timing

# Metrics
ada_reg_cv = AdaBoostRegressor(DecisionTreeRegressor(random_state=42),
                            n_estimators=200,
                            loss='linear', random_state=42)
ada_reg_cv_scores = cross_val_score(ada_reg_cv, X_train_trees, y_train,
                                    scoring='neg_mean_squared_error',
                                    cv=5)
ada_reg_cv_scores = np.sqrt(-ada_reg_cv_scores)

print('CV RMSE:', ada_reg_cv_scores.mean())
print('CV Std:', ada_reg_cv_scores.std())

# Timing
ada_reg_cv_time = (time.time() - start_time)
print('\nRunning Time: {}'.format(datetime.timedelta(seconds=ada_reg_cv_time)))
```

The output is actually an extremely high RMSE (way too high to be an accurate measure). I ran these lines separately and found that line 11 `ada_reg_cv_scores = np.sqrt(-ada_reg_cv_scores)` returns nan because it's taking the root of a negative number.

Then when I run it without the (-) sign inside the sqrt, I get the correct RMSE. So why are the 'neg_mean_squared_error' values positive?

Answer (score 0):

Once I tuned the DecisionTreeRegressor within the AdaBoostRegressor (`max_depth=5`), the neg_mean_squared_error returned negative, as it should. So I'm guessing the error has something to do with how unregularized the decision tree was, as the error of the tree model was likely 0.

Answer (score 0):

I had that error once when **I had untreated categorical features** in my dataset for an XGBoost model (aka the categorical features were strings still).
I had that while using *cross_validate()* function, such as:

```
evaluations = cross_validate(xgb_regressor, X_train, y_train, 
                             scoring=("neg_mean_squared_error"), 
                             cv=5, return_estimator=False)
```

Once I transformed the categorical data to numerical the problem was gone!